# Why don't we have LTE EARFCN for frequency in decimal to second place?

Tags: lte

EARFCN 3302 means 2675.20 MHz
EARFCN 3303 means 2675.30 MHz

What about 2675.25 MHz?
Why don't we have values defined for decimals with two places.

Comment: Because the raster of 100kHz is a good tradeoff between flexibility and complexity.

Comment: So it can be possible but due to above reason we avoid it @AlexTP?

Comment: Not really. In short, this is just a choice that TSG people agree with. For example, you can define EARFCN 3302 = 2675.25MHz and EARFCN 3303 = 2675.35MHz and technically nothing changes. Just TSG RAN guys thought that integers multiple of 100KHz look nicer.

Comment: Because we are talking about specification, then an EARFCN means a frequency multiple of 100KHz *by definition*. Therefore, no, it cannot be possible.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://www.mpirical.com/glossary/earfcn-e-utra-absolute-radio-frequency-channel-number) (bolding mine):

> Since the E-UTRA operates with more flexibility than UMTS , a updated
> method of identifying the centre carrier frequencies is used. **The
> carrier frequency in the uplink and downlink is designated by the
> EARFCN (E-UTRA Absolute Radio Frequency Channel Number) in the range 0
> – 65535. The channel raster is 100KHz for all bands, which means that
> the carrier centre frequency must be an integer multiple of 100KHz.**
> The relation between EARFCN and the carrier frequency in MHz for the
> downlink/uplink is given by an equation and associated table of
> frequency bands.

So each channel must be separated by 100kHz, whereas your suggestion gives a spacing of 50kHz.